# AWS S3 object taggin via management console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

As per the AWS S3 FAQ, it says - [Link](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/)

> Q. How do I apply Object Tags to my objects?
>
> You can add tags to new objects when you upload them or you can add them to existing objects. Up to ten tags can be added to each S3 object and you can use either the **AWS Management Console**, the REST API, the AWS CLI, or the AWS SDKs to add object tags.

but when I try to upload objects into a bucket via the management console, I have never been prompted to add tags. For Eg: in properties tab, I can only set metadata for the objects that I am uploading.

[image]

However, this is not the case after uploading the objects, I can individually go to each object and tag them.

It seems that the tagging is supported in API, [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-tagging.html)

> Other API Operations that Support Tagging
>
> PUT Object – You can specify tags when you create objects. You specify tags using the x-amz-tagging request header.

Please let me know whether it is possible to add tags to objects when uploading or add tags to set of selected objects at once using AWS management console?

Answer (score 0):

It is under the meta data section and I am sure when I was asking this question it was not there.

[image]